# Should I disable btrfs CoW for /var/lib/docker?

Tags: docker, btrfs

I saw that it is not a good idea to use btrfs CoW functionality for big files, such as data directories of a PostgreSQL database.

Since I use docker for databases, I now ask myself, if I should disable CoW for the whole `/var/lib/docker` directory. But I'm not sure, because docker's layered filesystem makes use of this feature, or not?

Or is it possible, to disable CoW for just some specific volumes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `docker` directly plugs into BTRFS (or any filesystem) CoW behavior; rather, it can use snapshots and/or reflinks to avoid replicating entire container images.

While disabling CoW will be surely benefical for performance, be aware that:

- disabling it means no data checksum, so no protection against data loss;
- snapshotting a volume automatically re-enables CoW;
- reflink will not work anymore;
- existing file will remain CoW-enabled (until you delete and recreate them).

While for a database (as PostgreSQL) the above points can be non-issues (ie: data checksum is done at the DB record level and snapshots are provided by the transactional layer), for a VM or container missing these features can be problematic.

Anyway, I really suggest you to read the [BTRFS FAQ about nodatacow](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Can_copy-on-write_be_turned_off_for_data_blocks.3F)

Comment: When using docker on top of a btrfs filesystem, it creates a directory called `/var/lib/docker/btrfs` containing BTRFS subvolumes. So this looks like docker plugs into filesystem specific features.

Comment: Thank you @shodanshok! I'm a bit confused about phrase "snapshotting a volume automatically re-enables CoW", I thought that if I make a snapshot of a volume, then it will do CoW only once to avoid changing the file in the snapshot, am I wrong then?

Comment: @Slabko you are right, but consider that frequent snapshots will cause many CoW "cycles"

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
    "storage-driver": "btrfs"
}
```

and disable copy-on-write on your volumes if they contain databases:

```
mkdir /var/lib/docker/volumes
chattr +C /var/lib/docker/volumes
```

Hoping that helps.

Comment: It's important, that the directory does not exists yet. `chattr +C` on a directory does only affect new files and directories in it. Enabling `nodatacow` on `/var/lib/docker/volumes` is only affecting new volumes. You should not disable CoW totally. I recommend to use a prepared directory as bind mount for database files and writeable image files.